# Error in Plaid API

Tags: plaid

I am using the plaid.  After generation of public token creater access token with exchange api. Now access token use to create api call but gives error.

> The provided API keys are not enabled for the Stripe ACH integration. please see https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe for more information

Can someone help to fix this?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [display_message] => 
    [error_code] => INVALID_PRODUCT
    [error_message] => the provided API keys are not enabled for the Stripe ACH integration. please see https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe for more information
    [error_type] => INVALID_INPUT
    [request_id] => KQQ56
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Enable Stripe integration in the Plaid dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Plaid docs (https://plaid.com/docs/api/#invalid-request-errors) the INVALID PRODUCT code means you need to upgrade from the free tier by contacting sales.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete integration plaid with stripe. On stripe you need to provide a valid bank account no.

If you in sandbox environment.

You can provide plaid sandbox bank account from here while filling complete stripe connect auth form.
https://plaid.com/docs/auth/coverage/testing/